# Environment error while installing selenium package in python

Tags: python, selenium

-------ERROR MESSAGE-----

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4bQM.jpg

-----message-----

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1108)')))

Answer (score 0):

Writing this as an answer as I can't comment yet. I used to get that error a lot when working on corporate network. An easy fix was setting up the correct proxy for pip. You can set the proxy settings in multiple places ([docs here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server)), but I found the easiest using pip like this:

pip install --proxy=https://yourproxyhere:port selenium

Or any package you want to install, at the end. Setting up an env var did not work for me, but using the proxy in the command usually did the trick.